# Play Framework WebSocket Handling

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket

In the following bit of code:

```
  def myRequest: WebSocket[JsValue, JsValue] =
    WebSocket.acceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue] { request => out =>

      val filtered: Set[Long] = // how to get the request body???

      WebSocketActor.props(filtered, out)
    }
```

How can I get access to the request body so that I could do some filtering on it before that content gets passed in to the Actor instance? The documentation from Play framework is not pretty clear. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can't.

This is because initial http request for websocket connection (i.e Upgrade) should not contain body as it's nothing more than a simple GET request. And it's treated as such by Play Framework by giving you `RequestHeader` (`Request` without body) instead `Request` object.

If you need to pass data from client to look at in server like credential or auth token, you can still make use of either `Authorization` header or simple query string.

Also note that Play's websocket documentation is [currently outdated](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5057) even though `acceptWithActor` and its variants are deprecated in new play 2.5.x in favor of `acceptOrResult` and its friends using `Flow` from akka-stream.